# How to install this window update kb5021233?

Tags: windows-10, updates

When I run windows updates through control panel, it always gives me:
Error code: (0x8007000d)

So I downloaded msu of that particular update from this [site](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/home.aspx) and while installing
this error pops up:

[image]

How to install this window update kb5021233?

Comment: What version of windows are you using?

Comment: https://windows101tricks.com/windows-10-update-fails-to-install/

Comment: Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter   ....   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-troubleshooter-19bc41ca-ad72-ae67-af3c-89ce169755dd   ...  and then try updating via Windows Update, not the update catalogue.  ...  That update is a recent cumulative update and installed fine here.

Comment: In order to determine the reason your unable to install that particular update you would need to provide your Windows Update log. Be sure to provide a screenshot of `winver` and a Windows Update history while you are at it.

Answer (score 0):

I got that answer. I visited this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10 – and select “**Update Now**” .